# SDL2 linux memory leak reported by valgrind

Tags: c++, valgrind, gnu, sdl-2

just trying detecting some potential issues on a small SDL2 program under linux/GCC written in C++17

valgrind report a lot of noisy memory leak about `vg_replace_malloc.c` that are suggested to be ignored from the official documentation [(link)](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.intro)

> (Ignore the "vg_replace_malloc.c", that's an implementation detail.)

But later on on the analysis, there is a block of:

```
==9891== 256 bytes in 4 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2,243 of 2,414
==9891==    at 0x483980B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==9891==    by 0x40156B3: dl_open_worker (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.30.so)
==9891==    by 0x4E60407: _dl_catch_exception (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.30.so)
==9891==    by 0x40148FD: _dl_open (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.30.so)
==9891==    by 0x4EF139B: dlopen_doit (in /usr/lib64/libdl-2.30.so)
==9891==    by 0x4E60407: _dl_catch_exception (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.30.so)
==9891==    by 0x4E604D2: _dl_catch_error (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.30.so)
==9891==    by 0x4EF1B08: _dlerror_run (in /usr/lib64/libdl-2.30.so)
==9891==    by 0x4EF1429: dlopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libdl-2.30.so)
==9891==    by 0x493CC37: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.12.0)
==9891==    by 0x4941DC5: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.12.0)
==9891==    by 0x494C3CC: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.12.0)
```

I am wondering if it is some sort of library dependency or a false positive or is obscurely pointing at something related to my code....

Any one could give me more insight how to interpret that `definitely lost` bytes snippet?

Comment: Please post the code of the program.

Comment: As far as SDL goes, any leaks that are small and don't grow with number of frame or with time can be ignored. It's annoying, but trying to get a SDL program that don't report leaks has never worked for me.

Comment: @Acorn the program used to test is this (draft) "example" of this toy lib:
https://github.com/Raffaello/sdl2-vga-terminal/blob/v0.2/sdl2-vga-terminal/examples/sdl2-vga-terminal.cpp

Comment: I have recompiled SDL2 library from source, and i have a better output. I guess there was something with SDL2 library from the package repository (potentially missing debug info?).
So i guess was something from my compile side not properly set up.

Comment: anyway it seems to point to SDL2_Init method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with that output was using `SDL2` from package repository that are compiled without debug info.

Therefore recompiling the `SDL2` library from source, including debug info, made the `valgrind` reports a lot clearer and led to solve and understand the issues.